# Javascript: How to alter CSS transform in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a slideshow and employing the `transform` style of a div.

```js
const prevSlide = document.getElementById('prev-slide');
const nextSlide = document.getElementById('next-slide');

const slides = document.getElementById('slides');
const slideList = [document.getElementsByClassName('slide-li')];

let slideNode = slideList[0]
let slideWidth = slideNode[0].clientWidth;

let slide = 0;

nextSlide.addEventListener('click', function e(){
  if (slide <= 0 && slide > -(slideWidth * (slideNode.length - 1))){
    slide -= slideWidth;
    slidePx = slide.toString() + "px";
    slides.style.transform = "translate("+slidePx+", 0px);";
  }
  else{
    slide = 0;
    slides.style.transform = "translate(0px, 0px);";
  }
})
prevSlide.addEventListener('click', function e(){
  if (slide < 0){
    slide += slideWidth;
    slidePx = slide.toString() + "px";
    slides.style.transform = "translate("+slidePx+", 0px);";
  }
  else{
    slide = slideWidth * (slideNode.length - 1);
    slidePx = slide.toString() + "px";
    slides.style.transform = "translate("+slidePx+", 0px);";
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color : white;
  }
#slide-container {
  margin           : 0 auto;
  width            : 500px;
  overflow         : hidden;
  position         : relative;
  }
#slides {
  margin           : 0 auto;
  height           : 400px;
  width            : 2000px;
  overflow         : hidden;
  display          : block;
  transition       : 1s ease;
  }
#slides:after {
  content          : "";
  display          : table;
  clear            : both;
  }
.slide-li {
  margin           : 0;
  display          : inline;
  width            : 25%;
  overflow         : hidden;
  float            : left;
  }
.slide-li img {
  width            : 500px;
  margin           : auto;
  }
#prev-slide, 
#next-slide {
  color            : white;
  padding          : 10px;
  font-size        : 20px;
  cursor           : pointer;
  z-index          : 5;
  position         : absolute;
  top              : 40%;
  font-weight      : bold;
  text-decoration  : none;
  transition       : 0.5s ease;
  }
#prev-slide {
  left             : 0;
  }
#next-slide {
  right            : 0;
  }
#prev-slide:hover, 
#next-slide:hover {
  background-color : #000000aa;
  }
```

```html
<div id="slide-container">
  <div id="slides">
    <span class="slide-li"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1041/500/400/"></span>
    <span class="slide-li"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1035/500/400"></span>
    <span class="slide-li"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1040/500/400"></span>
  </div>
  <a class="btn" id="prev-slide">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="btn" id="next-slide">&#10095;</a>
</div>
```

When I try to click either button to slide the slideshow, it doesn't translate.

When I try to log the transform property, I don't see any.

I am pretty sure that I made a mistake concerning the transform property, but I can't find it. What is the problem?

Comment: is js script linked to your html?

Comment: Yes. It is. I accidentally deleted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just replace

```
slidePx = slide.toString() + "px";
slides.style.transform = `translate(${slidePx}, 0px);`;
```

by

```
 slides.style = `transform : translate(${slide}px, 0px)`
```

But  you can simplify your code to:

```js
const
  prevSlide  = document.getElementById('prev-slide')
, nextSlide  = document.getElementById('next-slide')
, slides     = document.getElementById('slides')
, slideList  = document.querySelectorAll('.slide-li')
, slideWidth = slideList[0].clientWidth
   ;
let slide = 0; 
   
nextSlide.onclick = e =>
  {
  slide = ++slide % slideList.length
  slides.style = `transform : translate(${-slide * slideWidth}px, 0px)`
  }
prevSlide.onclick = e =>
  {
  slide = (--slide + slideList.length) % slideList.length
  slides.style = `transform : translate(${-slide * slideWidth}px, 0px)`
  }
```

I also corrected other small errors

```js
const
  prevSlide = document.getElementById('prev-slide')
, nextSlide = document.getElementById('next-slide')
, slides    = document.getElementById('slides')
, slideList = [document.getElementsByClassName('slide-li')]
  ;
let 
  slideNode  = slideList[0]
, slideWidth = slideNode[0].clientWidth
, lastImgNo = slideNode.length - 1
, slide      = 0
  ;
nextSlide.onclick = e =>
  {
  if (slide <= 0 && slide > -(slideWidth * lastImgNo))
    { slide -= slideWidth }
  else
    { slide = 0 }
  slides.style = `transform : translate(${slide}px, 0px)`
  }
prevSlide.onclick = e =>
  {
  if (slide < 0)
    { slide += slideWidth }
  else
    { slide = slideWidth * lastImgNo * -1 }
  slides.style = `transform : translate(${slide}px, 0px)`
  }
```

```css
body {
  background-color : white;
  }
#slide-container {
  margin           : 0 auto;
  width            : 500px;
  overflow         : hidden;
  position         : relative;
  }
#slides {
  margin           : 0 auto;
  height           : 400px;
  width            : 2000px;
  overflow         : hidden;
  display          : block;
  transition       : 1s ease;
  }
#slides:after {
  content          : "";
  display          : table;
  clear            : both;
  }
.slide-li {
  margin           : 0;
  display          : inline;
  width            : 25%;
  overflow         : hidden;
  float            : left;
  }
.slide-li img {
  width            : 500px;
  margin           : auto;
  }
#prev-slide, 
#next-slide {
  color            : white;
  padding          : 10px;
  font-size        : 20px;
  cursor           : pointer;
  z-index          : 5;
  position         : absolute;
  top              : 40%;
  font-weight      : bold;
  text-decoration  : none;
  transition       : 0.5s ease;
  }
#prev-slide {
  left             : 0;
  }
#next-slide {
  right            : 0;
  }
#prev-slide:hover, 
#next-slide:hover {
  background-color : #000000aa;
  }
```

```html
<div id="slide-container">
  <div id="slides">
    <span class="slide-li"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1041/500/400/"></span>
    <span class="slide-li"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1035/500/400"></span>
    <span class="slide-li"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1040/500/400"></span>
  </div>
  <a class="btn" id="prev-slide">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="btn" id="next-slide">&#10095;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semicolons from within the string literals on your `style.transform` lines.

They should look like this:

```js
slides.style.transform = "translate("+slidePx+", 0px)";
```

Instead of this:

```js
slides.style.transform = "translate("+slidePx+", 0px)";
```

```js
const prevSlide = document.getElementById('prev-slide');
const nextSlide = document.getElementById('next-slide');

const slides = document.getElementById('slides');
const slideList = [document.getElementsByClassName('slide-li')];

let slideNode = slideList[0]
let slideWidth = slideNode[0].clientWidth;

let slide = 0;

nextSlide.addEventListener('click', function e(){
  if (slide <= 0 && slide > -(slideWidth * (slideNode.length - 1))){
    slide -= slideWidth;
    slidePx = slide.toString() + "px";
    slides.style.transform = "translate("+slidePx+", 0px)";
  }
  else{
    slide = 0;
    slides.style.transform = "translate(0px, 0px)";
  }
})
prevSlide.addEventListener('click', function e(){
  if (slide < 0){
    slide += slideWidth;
    slidePx = slide.toString() + "px";
    slides.style.transform = "translate("+slidePx+", 0px)";
  }
  else{
    slide = slideWidth * (slideNode.length - 1);
    slidePx = slide.toString() + "px";
    slides.style.transform = "translate("+slidePx+", 0px)";
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color : white;
  }
#slide-container {
  margin           : 0 auto;
  width            : 500px;
  overflow         : hidden;
  position         : relative;
  }
#slides {
  margin           : 0 auto;
  height           : 400px;
  width            : 2000px;
  overflow         : hidden;
  display          : block;
  transition       : 1s ease;
  }
#slides:after {
  content          : "";
  display          : table;
  clear            : both;
  }
.slide-li {
  margin           : 0;
  display          : inline;
  width            : 25%;
  overflow         : hidden;
  float            : left;
  }
.slide-li img {
  width            : 500px;
  margin           : auto;
  }
#prev-slide, 
#next-slide {
  color            : white;
  padding          : 10px;
  font-size        : 20px;
  cursor           : pointer;
  z-index          : 5;
  position         : absolute;
  top              : 40%;
  font-weight      : bold;
  text-decoration  : none;
  transition       : 0.5s ease;
  }
#prev-slide {
  left             : 0;
  }
#next-slide {
  right            : 0;
  }
#prev-slide:hover, 
#next-slide:hover {
  background-color : #000000aa;
  }
```

```html
<div id="slide-container">
  <div id="slides">
    <span class="slide-li"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1041/500/400/"></span>
    <span class="slide-li"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1035/500/400"></span>
    <span class="slide-li"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1040/500/400"></span>
  </div>
  <a class="btn" id="prev-slide">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="btn" id="next-slide">&#10095;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to put a semicolon while changing `transform` property with JS. Just use `` slides.style.transform = `translate(${slidePx}, 0px)`; ``

```js
const prevSlide = document.getElementById("prev-slide");
const nextSlide = document.getElementById("next-slide");

const slides = document.getElementById("slides");
const slideList = [document.getElementsByClassName("slide-li")];

let slideNode = slideList[0];
let slideWidth = slideNode[0].clientWidth;

let slide = 0;

nextSlide.addEventListener("click", function e() {
    if (slide <= 0 && slide >- slideWidth * (slideNode.length - 1)) {
        slide -= slideWidth;
        slidePx = slide.toString() + "px";
        slides.style.transform = `translate(${slidePx}, 0px)`;
    } else {
        slide = 0;
        slides.style.transform = "translate(0px, 0px)";
    }
});
prevSlide.addEventListener("click", function e() {
    if (slide < 0) {
        slide += slideWidth;
        slidePx = slide.toString() + "px";
        slides.style.transform = "translate(" + slidePx + ", 0px)";
    } else {
        slide = slideWidth * (slideNode.length - 1);
        slidePx = slide.toString() + "px";
        slides.style.transform = "translate(" + slidePx + ", 0px)";
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: white;
}
#slide-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
#slides {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 400px;
    width: 2000px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    transition: 1s ease;
}
#slides:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.slide-li {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
    width: 25%;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
}
.slide-li img {
    width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
}
#prev-slide,
#next-slide {
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}
#prev-slide {
    left: 0;
}
#next-slide {
    right: 0;
}
#prev-slide:hover,
#next-slide:hover {
    background-color: #000000aa;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="slide-container">
            <div id="slides">
                <span class="slide-li"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x600" /></span>
                <span class="slide-li"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x600" /></span>
                <span class="slide-li"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x600" /></span>
            </div>
            <a class="btn" id="prev-slide">&#10094;</a>
            <a class="btn" id="next-slide">&#10095;</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

That is all you need to solve your problem.